# Getting Empty content Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python-3.x

Am not very familiar with Beautifulsoup, for the life i cant seem to retrieve the table in this html. I parsed the html page using Beautiful Soup and i come up empty. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
url='https://definitivehc.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1044bb19da8d4dbfb6a96eb1b4ebf629&view=list&showFilters=false#data'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
bs4 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

table_body=bs4.find('table')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('th')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

So i could generate the header for the table, but could not retrive the data from the table itself. Here is the html:

```
<table class="dgrid-row-table" role="presentation">
<tr>
    <td class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0 field-HOSPITAL_NAME" 
     role="gridcell"><div>**Phoenix VA Health Care System (AKA Carl T Hayden VA 
     Medical Center)**</div>
    </td>
     :
     :
    <td....................</td>
    <td....................</td>
    <td....................</td>
    <td....................</td>
```

...and there are several other TDs. Am trying to capture all the values from the table. Here is my attempt so far:

```
url='https://definitivehc.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1044bb19da8d4dbfb6a96eb1b4ebf629&view=list&showFilters=false#data'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\lab\chromedriver")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
html = browser.page_source

soup = Soup(html, "html")


table_body=soup.find('table', {'class': 'dgrid-row-table', 'role': 'presentation'})
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

The column generates nothing when i run it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the table is populated dynamically.

Comment: The issue here is the page is actually javacript rendered (not static). You should look into selenium, pyppeteer or some similar solution (like spynner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://definitivehc.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1044bb19da8d4dbfb6a96eb1b4ebf629&view=list&showFilters=false#data"

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")

print(len(soup.find_all("table")))
print(soup.find("table", {"id": "dgrid_0-header"}))

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @DirtBit. I will try that.

Comment: Hi, so i can get the header for the table, but cannot retrieve the table itself.